# How to use DVD+RW (UDF) both in windows and linux?

Tags: linux, dvd, dvd-burning, udf

I have dvd+rw disk. I would like to create UDF file system on it to use
with windows 7 (and newer) and gentoo both. How must I prepare media and
what commands should use to mount it in linux?

What I tried:

1. In Windows:

   ```
   format /fs:UDF D:
   ```

   now windows is able to work with the media. Gentoo can safely read it in ro mode.

   On gentoo (as described in linux Documentation):

   ```
   pktsetup 0 /dev/sr0
   mount -t udf -o rw,noatime /dev/pktcdvd/pkcdvd0 /mnt
   cp <some> /mnt
   umount /mnt
   pktsetup -d 0
   ```

   after that media is broken - windows suggest to format it, gentoo
   can't locate superblock to mount.
2. In Windows:

   ```
   format /fs:UDF D:
   ```

   now windows is able to work with the media Gentoo can safely read it in ro mode.

   On gentoo:

   ```
   mount -t udf -o rw,noatime /dev/sr0 /mnt
   cp <some> /mnt
   umount /mnt
   ```

   after that windows can't read the media, but gentoo is ok.
3. In gentoo:

   ```
   mkudffs /dev/sr0
   mount -t udf -o rw,noatime /dev/sr0 /mnt
   cp <some> /mnt
   umount /mnt
   ```

   gentoo works fine with media, Windows can read the media, but it
   can't write or delete files on it.
4. In gentoo:

   ```
   mkudffs -r 0150 --media-type=dvd /dev/sr0
   mount -t udf -o rw,noatime /dev/sr0 /mnt
   ```

   mounts as readonly

   ```
   mount -t udf -o remount,rw /dev/sr0 /mnt
   cp <some> /mnt
   umount /mnt
   ```

   gentoo works fine with media, Windows can read the media, but it
   can't write or delete files on it.
5. In gentoo:

   ```
   pktsetup 0 /dev/sr0
   mkudffs /dev/pktcdvd/pktcdvd0
   mount -t udf -o rw,noatime /dev/pktcdvd/pkcdvd0 /mnt
   ```

   missing partition (can't read superblock) and windows can do nothing
   with the media.
6. Also, I tried to use "forget" and "ignore" in uid and gid options of mount, but gentoo's mount had problems with it:

   ```
   sudo mount -t udf -o rw,uid=frget,uid=ignore,gid=ignore,gid=forget /dev/sr0 /media/default
   mount: failed to parse mount options
   ```

Comment: Weird. Have you tried formatting specifying a revision (`format /fs:UDF /r:2.01 D:`)?

Answer (score 1):

As of 2016.11.21, the drivers/block/pktcd driver was marked as deprecated and suggested for removal "after a version or two" Linux kernel version releases. It is 2020.02.02 as of this writing.

Recompile the Linux kernel without "drivers/block/pktcdvd", format/mount the UDF formated DVD+RW disc/media, and you should be able directly write to the UDF mounted disc filesystem using simple cp/mv/rm filesystem commands. Mount with fstab `auto noatime,rw` or `autofs"-fstype=auto,noatime,rw"`, in the event you have a mix of iso9660 or UDF formatted discs.

This works with my LG WH16NS60 bluray drive.

It maybe easier for you to format the disc with UDF filesystem using MS Windows (tested here using Windows 10), otherwise use udftools `mkudffs -l TITLE /dev/sr0` and if necessary, `mkudffs -l TITLE --media-type=dvd /YOUR/DEVICE/FILE`.

Remember, do not re-format DVD+RW media!  Also, using "dvd+rw-format -lead-out" may increase compatibility or slow operations.

Can monitor /var/log/messages for writing/finalizing after each file operation or umount.